# How to export shap waterfall values to dataframe?

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, classification, predictive-modeling

I am working on a binary classification using random forest model, neural networks in which am using SHAP to explain the model predictions. I followed the tutorial and wrote the below code to get the waterfall plot shown below

```
row_to_show = 20
data_for_prediction = ord_test_t.iloc[row_to_show]  # use 1 row of data here. Could use multiple rows if desired
data_for_prediction_array = data_for_prediction.values.reshape(1, -1)
rf_boruta.predict_proba(data_for_prediction_array)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(rf_boruta)
# Calculate Shap values
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(data_for_prediction)
shap.plots._waterfall.waterfall_legacy(explainer.expected_value[0], shap_values[0],ord_test_t.iloc[row_to_show])
```

This generated the plot as shown below

[image]

However, I want to export this to dataframe and how can I do it?

I expect my output to be like as shown below. I want to export this for the full dataframe. Can you help me please?

[image]

**update - error message**

```
----> 1 pd.DataFrame({
      2     "Feature Name": ["Base value"] + [f"Feature {i}" for i in range(ord_test_t.shape[1])],
      3     "Contribution": (explainer.expected_value[0]) + list(shap_values[0])
      4 })

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    634         elif isinstance(data, dict):
    635             # GH#38939 de facto copy defaults to False only in non-dict cases
--> 636             mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
    637         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    638             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype, typ, copy)
    500         # TODO: can we get rid of the dt64tz special case above?
    501 
--> 502     return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)
    503 
    504 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype, verify_integrity, typ, consolidate)
    118         # figure out the index, if necessary
    119         if index is None:
--> 120             index = _extract_index(arrays)
    121         else:
    122             index = ensure_index(index)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in _extract_index(data)
    672             lengths = list(set(raw_lengths))
    673             if len(lengths) > 1:
--> 674                 raise ValueError("All arrays must be of the same length")
    675 
    676             if have_dicts:

ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
```

Answer (score 1):

The values plotted are simply the SHAP values stored in `shap_values`, where the SHAP value at index i is the SHAP value for the feature at index i in your original dataframe. The base value you mention is then simply the expected value stored in `explainer.expected_value`. Therefore, you should be able to quite easily create a dataframe yourself as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame({
    "Feature Name": ["Base value"] + [f"Feature {i}" for i in range(data_for_prediction.shape[1])],
    "Contribution": list(explainer.expected_value[0]) + list(shap_values[0])
})
```

Comment: thanks for your help. upvoted when I try this, I get an error - `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: Without knowing the line on which this error occurs it's difficult to pinpoint the issue, but it seems that one of the lists/arrays (likely `data_for_prediction.shape`) does not have the index it is trying to access.

Comment: Is there any simple way to write the 1st line in dataframe? Or can let me know what does it do? Is `data_for_prediction` is the input dataframe?

Comment: I also see that the line `list(explainer.expected_value[0]) throws error. It says `np.float64 is not iterable object`. Because there is only one element, it says we cannot create list/iterate?

Comment: I also updated the error message. would really be helpful if you can support me with this

Comment: Without taking over my exact code, have a look at the values stored in the `shap_values` variable, since those correspond to the values in the arrows in the plot you're showing. The base/start value is stored in `explainer.expected_value`. Using those arrays you can just you base python transforms to convert them into lists, and eventually convert the data to a pandas dataframe.

Comment: I already tried something like this to use a different list method `pd.DataFrame({
    "Feature Name": ["Base value"] + [f"{col}" for col in (pd.DataFrame(data).columns.tolist())],
    "Contribution": (explainer.expected_value[0].tolist()) + (shap_values[0].tolist())
})` but still it doesn't work - I get another error on `unsupported operands +`